# Does anybody know of a good QGIS symbol library that can be used in conjunction with the qgis2web plugin?

Tags: qgis, symbology, software-recommendations, qgis2web

I'm working on finalizing a map that details the preferred cycling routes through my city and am trying to use the qgis2web plugin to export an interactive map but I'm having some trouble exporting the marker symbols I would like to. I've been using a custom arrow symbol to show the direction each road is sloping but it won't export properly. I've been using Leaflet during export rather than OpenStreetMap layers or Mapbox GL. I saw on some other forums that people have had issues with this and that SVG symbol markers can't be processed by the plugin as of now.

Does anyone know of any workaround or a symbol library I can use that includes more than the few symbols from the default library?

Export also seems to be somewhat finicky with the way it exports some simple symbols as well, so I seek any insight on the situation.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but in December 2020, Klas Karlsson @klas-karlsson posted several tweets with a link to a huge SVG icons library on his Twitter account.  https://twitter.com/klaskarlsson/status/1342845687025856517

Comment: Another link:  https://twitter.com/klaskarlsson/status/1342856630229200896